# jQuery parsing XML .each undefined issue

Tags: jquery

I have a simple xml file that I'm looping over to set a ValueObject for each item node.  Each VO created is added to a LinkedList data structure.  The linkedList is instantiated outside the .each() loop.  However, for some reason, my linkedList instance returns "undefined" inside the loop.  For instance:

```
Model.prototype.setData = function(data) {  
    this.data = data;

    this.linkedList = new LinkedList();

    this.startItem = $(data).find('slideShow').attr('startItem');
    this.currentID = this.startItem || 1;

    $(data).find('item').each(function() {
        var imageVO = new ImageVO();
        imageVO.id = $(this).find('id').text();
        imageVO.image = $(this).find('image').text();
        imageVO.title = $(this).find('title').text();
        console.log(this.linkedList) //undefined
        this.linkedList.addNode(imageVO);
    });

    this.linkedList.currentNode = this.linkedList.findNodeByIndex(this.currentID);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this.linkedList` is revering to the `linkedList` property of the actual item of the `data` collection.

Try this:

```
var that = this;
$(data).find('item').each(function() {
    var imageVO = new ImageVO();
    imageVO.id = $(this).find('id').text();
    imageVO.image = $(this).find('image').text();
    imageVO.title = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log(that.linkedList) //undefined
    that.linkedList.addNode(imageVO);
});
```

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that the `console.log()` statement is for an attribute called `linkList`, not `linkedList`.

Comment: Thanks just noticed that too.  I fixed it above to account for "linkedList" not "linkList" (typo).  Thanks for the quick reply!  This answer just put a lot (about what I know in terms of javascript) into perspective.